# TensorRT running interferene on multible Images C++

Tags: c++, tensorrt

Im trying to run interference using TensorRT on two images. The model im using has the input tensor size of [1,2,180,180]. I have two images in the format [1,180,180]. how can i concatenate the two images so i get the needed format? I have the code that uploads one frame to the gpu and runs interference but i dont know how to modify it to take two.

The code i currently have:

```
cv::cuda::GpuMat gpu_frame;
gpu_frame.upload(img1);

std::vector<cv::cuda::GpuMat> chw;
for(size_t i = 0; i < channels; ++i){
chw.emplace_back(cv::cuda::GpuMat(input_size, CV_32FC1, gpu_input + i * input_width * input_height));
}
cv::cuda::split(gpu_frame, chw);
```

I get my input size, height and width from the dims extracted from my model, and the gpu_input is my input buffer.

I hope somebody can help me :-).